# how do you add the same column names in Pandas given the group name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has the same column names multiple times. I need to be able to add the values for the same column names and display the output. For example, I have this data frame:

df

```
Server      Model     Slot  Count40G Count40G
server1     Cisco      1     10       5
server1     Cisco      2     5        0
server1     Cisco      3     20       0
server1     Cisco      4     0        1
server1     Cisco      8     0        10
server2     IBM        5     10       1
server2     IBM        8     5        0
server2     IBM        9     0        5
```

resulting data frame needs to look like this:

```
    Server      Model     Slot  Count40G 
    server1     Cisco      1     15       
    server1     Cisco      2     5        
    server1     Cisco      3     20       
    server1     Cisco      4     1        
    server1     Cisco      8     10       
    server2     IBM        5     11       
    server2     IBM        8     5        
    server2     IBM        9     5
```

In this example, there are only 2 columns with the same name but it could be more columns with the same name.

I tried this:

```
cols=['Server', 'Model', 'Slot']
df.groupby(cols, level=1, axis=1).sum()
```

I am getting index out of bounds error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it can be done without dropping the column, but here's how it might be achieved: sum all the columns with this name along axis 1, save the results, drop the existing columns and create one new.

```
col_name = "Count40G"
col_sum = df[col_name].sum(axis=1)
df.drop(col_name, axis=1, inplace=True)
df[col_name] = col_sum
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Server  Model  Slot  Count40G
0  server1  Cisco     1        15
1  server1  Cisco     2         5
2  server1  Cisco     3        20
3  server1  Cisco     4         1
4  server1  Cisco     8        10
5  server2    IBM     5        11
6  server2    IBM     8         5
7  server2    IBM     9         5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

First find which columns are duplicated and then for each duplicated column set, take column-wise `sum`. Lastly, you drop the duplicated columns.

```
is_dup_cols = df.columns.duplicated()
for x in df.columns[is_dup_cols].unique():
    df[x] = df[x].sum(axis=1)

df = df.loc[:, ~is_dup_cols]
```